# Change string / object to Duration and sum

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas and python,
I have a CSV file which contains a duration column ( Time ) when I read the file it's read-only as a string and I can't sum it:

```
agents['Avg Handle Time'][1:10]
Out[12]: 
1          -
2    0:05:07
3          -
4          -
5          -
6    0:05:03
7          -
8          -
9          -
Name: Avg Handle Time, dtype: object
```

Comment: You can look into the module `datetime`. You can convert strings to datetime objects and then you can do calculations on datetime objects such as summing(substracting dates. The first step is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to make it a timedelta column

```
pandas.to_timedelta(df['Avg Handle Time'])

pandas.to_timedelta(df['Avg Handle Time']).to_series().sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

when you read your csv file, you need to parse the dates so they can be read as such. For example:

df = pd.read_csv('your_path.csv', parse_dates=['Avg Handle Time'])

After doing this, the type of your column will be date-type. Once you have done this try to sum it.

Comment: datetimes are subtly different than datetimes... but i think this works nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the column from string/object to timedelta type and then just sum it up

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({"AvgHandleTime": ['-', '0:05:07', '-', '-', '-', '0:05:03', '-', '-']})
    pd.to_timedelta(df['AvgHandleTime']).sum()
```